# SQL for dependency of events

Tags: sql

Hei,

i want to basically see the dependency of one event on another, for instance event 'X' was always followed by event 'Y' with most frequency in 10 mins and less frequency in next 20 mins and so on. I have below dataset

```
siteid    sitename    Asset        stdreason  reason     timestamp 
A         AB          Freezer      60         Testing    2017-05-01 00:01:00.000
A         ABc         Freezer1     61        Testing1   2017-05-01 00:15:00.000
B         AB          Freezer2     60        Testing    2017-05-01 00:01:00.000
```

so in output i want to calculate reason 'Testing' occured 10 times within different intervals i.e 5,10,20 mins of 'Testing1'.

It is a huge dataset with more than testing and testing1 events so its not limited to only these. above is used for example purposes only.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: few variations but without success.

Comment: show us what you have tried and why it didnt work, by editing it into the question

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: SQL server 2014